# Firebase Auth: How to unsubscribe from Auth observer after user creation and then subscribe again?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I am using the **`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`** method for signing up new users. Immediately after this user creation process, I am sending an email verification. Then, in my `onAuthStateChanged()` I have a condition to check whether the user has verified their email. The problem is that the Auth observer is logging out the user BEFORE the email `sendEmailVerification()` method is complete.

**Based on the below code, where is the best place to succuessfully unsubscribe the observer ? And, how to do it with Firebase JS SDK v9?**

Let me explain my use case and show my code:

**`pages/sign-up`:**

```js
async signUp() {
  const auth = getAuth()
  const batch = writeBatch(db)

  try {
    const UserCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      this.formValues.email,
      this.formValues.password
    )
    
    const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', UserCredential.user.uid)
    batch.set(userDocRef, {
      uid: UserCredential.user.uid,
      displayName: this.formValues.displayName,
      photoURL: `https://gravatar.com/avatar/${md5(
        this.formValues.email
      )}?d=identicon`
    })
    const usernameDocRef = doc(db, 'usernames', this.formValues.displayName)
    batch.set(usernameDocRef, { uid: UserCredential.user.uid })

    // Commit batch
    await batch.commit()
    console.log('batch committed, user is:', UserCredential.user.uid)
    await this.verifyEmail() // <-- user is logged out before this has a chance to fire!
```

**`verifyEmail()`**:

```js
async verifyEmail() {
  const auth = getAuth()
  const actionCodeSettings = {
    url: `${this.$config.baseUrl}/email-confirmation/success`
  }
  try {
    await sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser, actionCodeSettings)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An email verification error happened', error)
    this.errorMessage = error.message
  }
},
```

In my `onAuthStateChanged()` method, I am immediately logging out the user IF their email is not yet verified. This causes the following error:

[image]

And here is how I have my `onAuthStateChanged` observer set up (it runs before the page is rendered):

**`~/plugins/auth.js`:**

```js
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    if (!user.emailVerified) {
      // User has not verified the email yet
      store.dispatch('logOutUser')
    }
  // TO DO: finish up rest of user logic
```

Should the unsubscribe be in the `auth.js` or the `pages/sign-up` page? I am unsure how to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to perform certain actions after signup/login, then you should unsubscribe from auth observer as you've figured out.

```js
const authObserver = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  // ...
}

async signUp() {
  //unsubscribe here i.e when user clicks signup button
  authObserver() 
 
  const auth = getAuth()
  const batch = writeBatch(db)
  // ...
}
```

Do note that, if you you auth observer is meant to redirect logged in user somewhere else then it won't do it now. So make sure you do that manually.